# How can I view a post someone shared with me ONLY on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I saw a notification that someone has shared a private post + video with me, but now that notification has disappeared. All I can see in notification window are the posts to my YouTube videos, I can't find that private post anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure the person sharing it with you hasn't removed the post?

Comment: Does it show up on https://plus.google.com/stream/mentions